# Is it possible to deploy SharePoint solution (WSPs) via feature activation?

Tags: sharepoint, deployment, sharepoint-2007

this seems to me an uphill task in SharePoint but is it possible to deploy the WSPs via SharePoint features. For instance, if we activate a certain feature then some specific SharePoint solutions (WSPs) should be deployed on SharePoint farm.

Comment: Just curious, why would you want to deploy a solution via a feature? This seems weird to me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

You need to get a reference to the solution object itself via SPFarm.Solutions.

Once you have the SPSolution object, call Deploy (SPSolution.Deploy()) to deploy it.

SPSolutionCollection (returned by SPFarm.Solutions): http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.administration.spsolutioncollection_members.aspx

SPSolution Members: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.administration.spsolution_members.aspx